# Limit of a Sequence of Spiraling Points

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, polygons

**The Problem**

> Starting with the vertices $P_1(0,1), P_2(1,1), P_3(1,0), P_4(0,0)$ of a square, we construct further points as shown in the figure: $P_5$ is the midpoint of $P_1P_2$, $P_6$ is the midpoint of $P_2P_3$, $P_7$ is the midpoint of $P_3P_4$, and so on. The polygonal spiral path $P_1P_2P_3P_4P_5P_6P_7\cdots$ approaches a point $P$ inside the square. Find the coordinates of $P$.
> [*Calculus* by James Stewart, $7^\text{th}$ edition, chapter $11$, problem plus, problem $18$]
> [image]

**What I Have Tried**
First of all, let $P_n=(x_n,y_n)$. We will first consider only $x$-coordinates first because the $y$-coordinate of $P$ can be found similarly. I have proven using induction that $\tfrac12x_n+x_{n+1}+x_{n+2}+x_{n+3}=2$ for all $n\geq1$ as follows.

> Base Case ($n=1$)
> Since $x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=1, x_4=0$, we have $\tfrac12x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=\tfrac12\cdot0+1+1+0=2.$
> Induction ($n>1$)
> Assume that $\tfrac12x_n+x_{n+1}+x_{n+2}+x_{n+3}=2$ is true for $n=k$, then
> \begin{equation}
> x_{k+2}+x_{k+3}=2-\tfrac12x_k-x_{k+1}.
> \end{equation}
> Also observe that $x_{n+4}=\tfrac12(x_n+x_{n+1})$. Therefore
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> \tfrac12x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}+x_{k+3}+x_{k+4}&=\tfrac12x_{k+1}+(2-\tfrac12x_k-x_{k+1})+x_{k+4}\\\\
> &=\tfrac12x_{k+1}+2-\tfrac12x_k-x_{k+1}+\tfrac12(x_k+x_{k+1})\\\\ 
> &=2
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}
> and so it is true for $n=k+1$.

So if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ exists, we can apply the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$ to both sides of the equation to get (letting $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L_x$)
$$\tfrac12L_x+3L_x=2$$
or
$$L_x=\tfrac47.$$
**My Question**
The problem arises: how do we prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ does exist? All I've been able to do is prove that $0\leq x_n\leq1$ for all $n\geq1$. I couldn't find anything on the web that could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're not expected to prove that the limit exists, but to assume that it exists: "The polygonal spiral path [...] approaches a point $P$ inside the square." Still, it's good to prove it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_{n+4}=\tfrac12(x_n+x_{n+1})$$
$$u_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$$
$$u_{n+3}=\tfrac12(x_n+x_{n+1}-2x_{n+3})$$
$$=\tfrac12(-u_n-2u_{n+1}-2u_{n+2})$$
$$\vdots$$
$$u_{n+9}=\tfrac18(-u_n+2u_{n+2})$$
$$u_{n+10}=\tfrac18(-u_n-3u_{n+1}-2u_{n+2})$$
$$u_{n+11}=\tfrac18(u_n+u_{n+1}-u_{n+2})$$
$$|u_{n+9}|\leq\tfrac18(1+2)\max\{|u_n|,|u_{n+2}|\}$$
$$|u_{n+10}|\leq\tfrac18(1+3+2)\max\{|u_n|,|u_{n+1}|,|u_{n+2}|\}$$
$$|u_{n+11}|\leq\tfrac18(1+1+1)\max\{|u_n|,|u_{n+1}|,|u_{n+2}|\}$$
$$\max\{|u_{n+9}|,|u_{n+10}|,|u_{n+11}|\}\leq\tfrac68\max\{|u_n|,|u_{n+1}|,|u_{n+2}|\}$$
$$\max\{|u_{n+9}|,|u_{n+10}|,\cdots,|u_{n+17}|\}\leq\tfrac34\max\{|u_n|,|u_{n+1}|,\cdots,|u_{n+8}|\}$$
$$w_m=\max\{|u_{9m}|,|u_{9m+1}|,\cdots,|u_{9m+8}|\}\geq0$$
$$|u_n|\leq w_{\lfloor n/9\rfloor}$$
$$w_{m+1}\leq\tfrac34w_m$$
$$w_m\leq(\tfrac34)^mw_0$$
$$x_{n+k}-x_n=u_n+u_{n+1}+u_{n+2}+\cdots+u_{n+k-1}$$
$$|x_{n+k}-x_n|\leq|u_n|+|u_{n+1}|+\cdots+|u_{n+k-1}|$$
$$\leq w_{\lfloor n/9\rfloor}+w_{\lfloor(n+1)/9\rfloor}+\cdots+w_{\lfloor(n+k-1)/9\rfloor}$$
$$\leq\Big((\tfrac34)^{\lfloor n/9\rfloor}+(\tfrac34)^{\lfloor(n+1)/9\rfloor}+\cdots+(\tfrac34)^{\lfloor(n+k-1)/9\rfloor}\Big)w_0$$
$$\lfloor\tfrac n9\rfloor>\tfrac n9-1$$
$$|x_{n+k}-x_n|\leq\Big((\tfrac34)^{n/9-1}+(\tfrac34)^{(n+1)/9-1}+\cdots+(\tfrac34)^{(n+k-1)/9-1}\Big)w_0$$
$$=w_0\,(\tfrac34)^{n/9-1}\Big(1+(\tfrac34)^{1/9}+(\tfrac34)^{2/9}+\cdots+(\tfrac34)^{(k-1)/9}\Big)$$
$$=\tfrac43w_0\,\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}^{\,n}\Big(1+\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}+\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}^{\,2}+\cdots+\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}^{\,k-1}\Big)$$
$$=\tfrac43w_0\,\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}^{\,n}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}^{\,k}}{1-\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}}\right)$$
$$\leq\tfrac43w_0\,\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}^{\,n}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt[9]{\tfrac34}}\right)$$
$$\to0,\quad n\to\infty$$

Comment: I have a suspicion that there's an easier way...

Comment: I remember someone commented to apply $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ to the equation. Also, how did you even come up with such a solution?

Comment: I was the one who mentioned limsup and liminf, thinking you could just apply them to your equation to get $\tfrac72L_+=2=\tfrac72L_-$, but I was forgetting that they're not linear.